# Mac OS 10.10 users connecting smb shares can't be disconnected

Tags: windows, mac-osx, file-sharing

So we have a bunch of windows file servers (2008 R2 and up) sharing up content using windows permissioning (SMB not AFP using Active Directory users).  Sharing files across the network works ok until someone tries to rename a folder.  They get an error message stating that an administrator needs to authenticate.

However, the rights are correct.  It's a bad error message.  Now, if they dismount the server, we are able to rename as normal from the server.  If I try to disconnect their session from the server the timer resets to 00:00 and doesn't disconnect.  It seems the finder auto reconnects.  Now the real issue that if multiple users try to connect to the same folder the whole path is locked until they both dismount the server and so on.

So, has anyone else run into this issue?  We raised it with Apple and they say its a known bug with their SMB implementation and might get around to fixing it.  Any work around from the server side?  Settings that can be adjusted from the Mac client?  Some setting that tells the finder to not lock onto files for an extreme amount of time?  The only fix we are seeing online is to use EZ-IP which exposes AFP to the finder which we are getting away from since AFP is being deprecated.

Thanks.